# AngularJS Custom directives Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Learning AngularJS and I can't seem to see what's wrong with my custom directives.  Using a modified w3 school code to show a simpler example of my problem.

When I lunch the demo.html in google chrome I only get a white screen.

Top snip - demo.html
Bottom snip - app.js

```js
(function(){

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    var direc = function() 
    {
        return 
        {
            restrict : 'A',
            template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
        };
    };
    
    app.directive("w3TestDirective", direc);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        
        <div w3-test-directive></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error: You do not need a closing parantheses while defininig direc function.

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    var direc = function() 
    {
        return 
        {
            restrict : 'A',
            template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
        }
    };// You had extra closing parantheses here

      app.directive("w3TestDirective", direc);
})();
```

Comment: I made you change and I'm still not getting anything.